# Plotting json data using google charts

Tags: json, google-visualization

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">


  google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});

  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart(){

    var options = {
                   'width':400,
                   is3D:true ,
                   'height':300};

    var name = "emp_name";
    $.ajax({
        url : "data.json",
        dataType : "JSON"
    }).done(function(data)
            {
                var nameArray = [["state",name]];
                $.each(data.Details,function(){
                    var stateitem = [this.emp_name,this[name]];
                    nameArray.push(stateitem);
                });

            var statesData = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(statesArray);

            var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_id'));
            chart.draw(statesData, options);
        });
  }
</script>
```

```
<div id="chart_id"></div>
```

I am new to google visualization concepts , i want to a pie chart showing total working hours of each employee , from reading a json data file , which is shown below.

{"Details":
    [
        { "emp_name": "ABC", "works_on": "wheels", "time_from": "2012-03-27 10:00:00", "time_to": "2012-03-27 12:00:00" },
        { "emp_name": "xyz", "works_on": "seat", "time_from": "2012-03-27 14:00:00", "time_to": "2012-03-27 17:00:00" },
        { "emp_name": "ABC", "works_on": "painting", "time_from": "2012-03-28 10:00:00", "time_to": "2012-03-28 12:00:00" },
        { "emp_name": "xyz", "works_on": "tube", "time_from": "2012-03-28 14:00:00", "time_to": "2012-03-28 17:00:00" },
        { "emp_name": "pqr", "works_on": "engine", "time_from": "2012-03-29 10:00:00", "time_to": "2012-03-29 12:00:00" },
        { "emp_name": "ABC", "works_on": "wiper", "time_from": "2012-03-29 14:00:00", "time_to": "2012-03-29 17:00:00" },
        { "emp_name": "mno", "works_on": "air_cooler", "time_from": "2012-03-30 10:00:00", "time_to": "2012-03-30 12:00:00" },
        { "emp_name": "ABC", "works_on": "wheels", "time_from": "2012-03-30 14:00:00", "time_to": "2012-03-30 17:00:00" }
 ]}

Comment: I have done this much please help me.

Comment: Then tell us what your problem is. Is the chart not showing? Is it showing the wrong data? Is it something else? You should also go over the formating of the question, e.g. format the JSON data into a code block.

Comment: Also: Are you aware that with `var name = "emp_name"` `this.emp_name` and `this[name]` reult in the same value?

Comment: Thank you for your reply , no i dont have any idea about those things , i got it on some web site.

Comment: And i want to calculate difference between "time_from" and "time_to" and by using that value want to plot pie chart using google chart.please help me.

Comment: And that is not displaying anything , i am getting a blank screen and if i click on inspect element and click on console i am getting this error : ""XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///Coding_part/Using_google_chart/data.json. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.""